# Cómo resolver TypeError: unsupported format string passed to method.__format__ python

Tags: python-3.x

necesito que se me devuelva un texto que contenga nombre, puntaje, dificultad. Los primeros dos los toma bien, el problema es el tercero.
El código que tengo es:

```
def __init__(self, nombre, puntaje = 0, dificultad ='facil', avatar = None):
    self.__nombre = nombre
    self.__puntuacion = puntaje
    self.__dificultad = dificultad
    self.__avatar = avatar


def __str__(self):
    return '{:^15} {:5} {:^15} {:^5} {:^15}'.format(self.__nombre,' ', self.__puntuacion,' ',self.__dificultad)
#def infoJugador(self):
```

El error que sale es el del título = TypeError: unsupported format string passed to method.**format**

Sucede cuando se invoca este método

```
def actualizar_puntaje (puntaje,ventana):
listado_puntos =''
for p in range(len(puntaje.puntajes)):
    listado_puntos = listado_puntos + str(puntaje.puntajes[p]) + '\n'
    ventana['puntos'].update(value=listado_puntos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví modificando así el infoJugador (sería el **str**)

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.__nombre} - {self.__puntuacion} - {self.__dificultad}"
```

y lo invoco así:

```
for p in range(len(puntaje.puntajes)):
    listado_puntos = listado_puntos + str(puntaje.puntajes[p].infoJugador().upper()) + '\n'
```